# Angular: error when using BehaviorSubject<this> in base class and assigning typof ChildClass to typeof BaseClass

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a very strange issue: I have code that runs in typescript strict mode, but won't compile in Angular. The culprit seems to be `BehaviorSubject<this>`, other generic typed fields don't cause issues.

Here's the code:

```
class SomeGeneric<T> {}

class BaseClass {
  /* comment or uncomment the line below */
  public thisSubject$: BehaviorSubject<this | null> | undefined;
  public thisPromise: Promise<this> | undefined;
  public thisSome = new SomeGeneric<this>();
}

class ExtClass extends BaseClass {
  public anotherField: number = 0;
}

function takesCtor(ctor: typeof BaseClass) {
  console.log(ctor);
}

takesCtor(ExtClass);
```

The error message when this code is put into an Angular project's source (occurring at last line, where I try to pass the child class constructor to a function that expects the base class constructor):

```
Argument of type 'typeof ExtClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof BaseClass'.
Construct signature return types 'ExtClass' and 'BaseClass' are incompatible.
The types of 'thisSubject$' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'BehaviorSubject<ExtClass | null> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<BaseClass | null> | undefined'.
Type 'BehaviorSubject<ExtClass | null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<BaseClass | null>'.
Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
Type 'Observer<ExtClass | null>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<BaseClass | null>[]'.
Type 'Observer<ExtClass | null>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<BaseClass | null>'.
Type 'BaseClass | null' is not assignable to type 'ExtClass | null'.
```

And the excerpt from tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
```

Here's a StackBlitz of a minimal Angular app having the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmsfuf?file=src/main.ts

And here's a StackBlitz of a minimal plain TypeScript project not having the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dufytr?file=index.ts

**My question is**

How do I get this code - that compiles in plain TypeScript - to compile in Angular? What Angular package could cause the error? Since it happens in one project but not in the other, I assume it's a package. Or an Angular compiler option. Any ideas where to look at?

Comment: the issue i'm seeing here is that you are trying to check `function takesCtor(ctor: typeof BaseClass) ` when the type should be `function takesCtor(ctor: typeof ExtClass) {`

Comment: That's not the real Issue. The takesCtor function shall take any ctor/class that extends BaseClass. If I explicitly type it `typeof ExtClass` I won't be able to pass BaseClass any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `this` as a type. Consider specifying the type explicitly.

```
class BaseClass {
  /* comment or uncomment the line below */
  public thisSubject$: BehaviorSubject<BaseClass | null> | undefined;
  public thisPromise: Promise<BaseClass> | undefined;
  public thisSome = new SomeGeneric<BaseClass>();
}
```

Here's the fork of your example where everything works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ntrewa?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That's the first time I hear "never use `this` as a type". I have two issues with your answer:
I use `this` as a type because `thisPromise` and `thisSubject$` will always "resolve" an object of `this` type, meaning an instance of ExtClass has `thisPromise` resolving an instance of ExtClass - with your suggestion I'd have to manually convince TS in `then` that I got an ExtClass, whereas by using `this` as type there TS already knows that.
The other issue is: `Promise<this>` works, but `BehaviorSubject<this>` doesn't.

Comment: @Holzchopf in this case use generic `T extends BaseClass` and then specify `T` everywhere.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Of course, both your suggestions make the error disappear. I'd still like to use `this` as type because that let's TS infer the actual type (when using a child class) of those generic properties. Since exactly that is possible in TypeScript, with the code I posted, I have to assume the error is introduced by Angular.

I updated the initial post to make it clearer that the question is about an Angular configuration issue, not a TypeScript issue.

Comment: @Holzchopf angular has nothing to do with typescript compilation process, your error might be somehow related to specific typescript compilerOptions, but I'm not sure (probably setting `strict: false` will make the error disappear, but you should never go that way). Anyway, the error you see is completely valid, because you're specifying non-abstact type in one place and expect it to be equal to another one in other place

Comment: My original question includes two Stackblitz links: One to a TypeScript project where that code is working the way I expect and one to an Angular project where the same code causes compiler errors. Both projects have similar compilerOptions (i.e. both have `strict: true`). My guess is, Angular either overwrites some compilerOptions or sets different defaults for options I haven't declared in the `.tsconfig`. Please, can you help me compare the two and tell me find out what I've overlooked?